# R: Add a curve,with my own equation, to an x,y scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, curve

I want to add a curve with the following equation to an x,y scatterplot: 
y<-(105+0.043(x^2-54x)). Is it possible within the plot() function? Also, if I use qplot instead (ggplot2) is there a way to draw this curve?

Comment: Use `curve()` for base plots and `stat_function()` for ggplot2.

Answer (score 11):

```
# data for scatterplot
x = rnorm(10, sd = 10)
y = (105 + 0.043 * (x^2 - 54 * x)) + rnorm(10, sd = 5)
```

Base plotting

```
plot(x, y)
curve(105 + 0.043 * (x^2 - 54 * x), add = T)
```

For ggplot, we need a data.frame

```
dat = data.frame(x = x, y = y)

ggplot(dat, aes(x , y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) 105 + 0.043 * (x^2 - 54 * x))
```

Comment: You could also do `qplot(...) + stat_function(...)`.